# Using a custom javascript script file with durandal template

Tags: single-page-application, durandal

I work on a Visual Studio 2012 MVC4 Project with the **Durandal template**. In this template, the shell.js page gives us a quite simple menu solution where every elements are located on top. Personally I need something different. For that purpose, I have a javascript file named dropdown.js which allows me to show/hide sub menus. It works pretty well in a standard project but I was not able to do it working with the durandal template.

Here is what I try:

I added a reference to the dropdown.js script in the Index.chtml:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/dropdown.js"></script>
```

Then in the shell.html page, I would like to use it like this:

```
<li class="dropdown" data-role="dropdown">
    ...
    ...
</li>
```

Here is a little portion of the dropdown.js:

```
$(function () {
    alert('XXXX');
    $('[data-role="dropdown"]').each(function () {
        alert('YYYY');
        $(this).Dropdown();
    })
})
```

As you can see, each element decorated with the 'dropdown' class should have been catched. It doesn't work with durandal. I placed some alert boxes to check it. The alert 'XX' is showed but the alert 'YY' is never showed.

I searched a bunch of hours without success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that when the dropdown.js function is executed before the menu renders and because of that the jquery selector doesn't catch any list item.

I think that your best option is to make a knockout binding to transform your list items in dropdowns.

The binding would look something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dropdown= {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(element).Dropdown();
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    }
};
```

And in the view:

```
<li class="dropdown" data-bind="dropdown : {}">
    ...
    ...
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the life cycle events tha tyou can tap into for [Durandal here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/)

viewAttached may help since you can tap into when the view and dom are ready.

Comment: I was using `viewAttached` to get things done as well, but according to this discussion at [github](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues/74#issuecomment-14291074), custom bindings or Durandal widgets should be considered first before going down that route.

Comment: It depends ... if you just need to wait for the DOM to be ready, viewAttached is fine. If you need more, a binding is ideal.

Comment: Not exactly the way I understand Rob's recommendation, but I've to admit that the documentation is not 100% clear about when to use which hook in order to work according to Durandal's philosophy.

Comment: I asked Rob to put use cases in the docs ... I think that will clarify. I agree that binding handlers are cleaner, but viewAttached is OK if you are OK with your jQuery code being in the viewmodel. I prefer  handlers, too, for what its worth.